# Find efficient solution of complement number

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have been given a positive integer and asked output its complement number.

i.e.

```
Input: 5
Output: 2
```

**Explanation:**

The binary representation of `5` is `101` (no leading zero bits), and its complement is `010`. So I need to output `2`.

The following solution works but I feel it is not the most efficient algorithm. Can anyone spot any way this could be improved? Most likely using a bitwise operator.

```js
/**
 * @param {number} num
 * @return {number}
 */
var findComplement = function(num) {

  var bin = Number(num).toString(2);

  bin = bin.split('');
  var answer = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < bin.length; i++) {
    if (bin[i] === '0') {
      answer.push(1);
    } else {
      answer.push(0)
    }
  }

  return parseInt(answer.join(''), 2);

};

console.log(findComplement(5));
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Pat you're right, this is probably not the correct arena for this question, apologies!

Answer (score 3):

Check function `complement`

### How does it work?

First we use the complement operator `~` but it returns a 32 bit result, so for `~5` is equal to `4294967290` (29 `1` and `010` totaling 32 bits). Next we need to strip those leading `1`, so we create a mask of the same length of our number in binary format, that is for `5` (`101`) the mask is `111` i.e. `7`. Using the `&` operator for the complement and our number, we get the proper result.

Hope it is clear :)

### Code

you can also run the snippet to test it

```js
function complement(n) {
   var mask = Math.pow(2, n.toString(2).length) - 1;
   return ~n & mask;
}
```

```html
input <input id="value" type="number" value="5" onchange="document.getElementById('result').textContent = complement(parseInt(document.getElementById('value').value))"/>
result: <span id="result">2</span>
```

Comment: Or `return mask - n`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be faster but its a one liner:

```
const complement = (n) => n.toString(2).split('').map((e) => e === '0' ? 1 : 0).join('', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, the code should be close to this:

```js
var findComplement = function(num) {

    /* Skip leading zeros */
    var power;
    for (power = 31; power >= 0 && ((num & (1 << power)) === 0); power--);

    /* Iterate through the rest of the number */
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < power; i++) {
        if ((num & (1 << i)) === 0)
            result |= (1 << i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

However, there's one thing I'm not sure about: as far as I know `Number` type is a 64-bit floating-point number type. Since representation of floating-point numbers and integer numbers is different ([check this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory)), the answer might be not what you would expect if you looked through all 64 bits. I might be wrong, so correct me if it's so.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do in JavaScript.

```
const findComplement = (num) => {
  return parseInt(
    num
      .toString(2)
      .split('')
      .map((i) => +!+i)
      .join(''),
    2
  );
};
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `+!+` there?

Answer (score 0):

Tips and tricks for number complement.

```js
var findComplement = (num) => {
  const mask = parseInt((+num).toString(2).replace(/\d/g, '1'), 2);
  return num ^ mask;
};

console.log(findComplement(5));
```